# How do I use a web.xml file with noir?

Tags: clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty, noir

I'm writing a web app in clojure, and want to edit Jetty's settings. One way to do this is to use a web.xml file. How do I use a web.xml file with Jetty?

Comment: What do you want to customize?

Comment: gzip. I have a different question asking about that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145891/how-do-i-programmatically-set-gzip-in-jetty), but if I can get web.xml going in noir, it solves it.

Comment: Would [ring-gzip-middleware](https://github.com/mikejs/ring-gzip-middleware) work?

Comment: No, ring-gzip-middleware is very broken. I'm not sure why actually, but I would prefer using jetty's built-in stuff than trying to fix an unmaintained package.

Comment: https://github.com/amalloy/ring-gzip-middleware This fork should work fine.

Comment: @Rayne does it work with clojure 1.3?